# Need help in rendering 20 second's motion graphic to 10 second

Tags: adobe-after-effects

This is my first day practicing with Adobe After Effects. I got tutorial from youtube and was working on it. I successfully did what was in tutorial and one thing neither I noticed nor mentioned in video.

I have done a simple motion graphic video in Adobe After Effects and it completes in 20 seconds. The problem is that the result in video of animation is very slow.
I want it to be faster with same "30 frame per second" and complete in 10 second or below.

When I try to rescale from the time line, it removes some of the animation of object.

How do decrease that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna show two methods as they can both be useful, even though they both do the same thing in this case.

You are not winning time by choosing either one of these. Method 1 is versatile in the sense that you can choose exactly the layers you wish to speed up or speed down. With Method 2 you have to speed up or speed down the whole comp, but it leaves the old slower comp intact and each time you update the old comp, the new one is updated.

**Method 1:**

1. Select all layers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

   - Alternatively you can select only those layers you wish to speed up or slow down.
2. Top menu: `Layer > Time > Time Stretch...`.

   - Enter new duration and press ok.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to change the comp duration to match.

> On a Mac, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

---

**Method 2:**

1. Make a new comp <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

   - I'm going to call the old comp `Comp 1`.
   - I'm going to call the new comp `Comp 2`.
2. Drag `Comp 1` into `Comp 2`.

   - Make `Comp 2` the active comp.
3. Top menu: `Layer > Time > Time Stretch...`.

   - Enter new duration and press ok.
   - Alternatively just resize the `Comp 2` footage in the timeline by grabbing the right side and dragging it.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to change the comp duration to match.

Since with this method you end up with more than one Comp, remember to select the comp(s) you wish to export, before adding it to media encoder queue.

> On a Mac, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: +1 I was trying to compete with you this week but screw that :)

Comment: @joojaa [There can be only one!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Octc4.jpg)

Comment: I used the method one and I got that I need to make it 3 second instead of 10 to make it faster as I want